# Why has Terraform stopped working on GCP project

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I had a terraform deployment that deployed GKE cluster pools on GCP and it stopped working.

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_container_cluster.primary: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_container_cluster.primary: Post 
https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/...-gcp-poc/zones/europe-
west1-d/clusters?alt=json: dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

I can still deploy manually via console

I can still deploy it with gcloud cli

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster_name --zone europe-west1-b
```

I tried changing the credentials json file to no avail.

It happened after an upgrade from google plugin 1.4 to 1.5 
My mac was restarted since.

Comment: What happens if you curl that endpoint? It looks like it's just timing out which suggest firewalls/network connectivity.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
} . I would need to arrange the http request

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the .terraform folder and replacing it with an old one I had with google plugin 1.4

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

This worked even though I got this error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_container_cluster.rtp_container_cluster: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_container_cluster.rtp_container_cluster: Error reading 
instance group manager returned as an instance group URL: Get 
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/rtp-gcp-
poc/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-rtp-container-
cluste-default-pool-8bb9aa85-grp?alt=json: dial tcp: i/o timeout

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

then I connected via kubectl

```
➜  ~ kubectl get node
NAME                                                  STATUS    ROLES     
AGE       VERSION
gke-...-container-cluste-default-pool-8bb9aa85-7kcb   Ready     <none>    
14m       v1.8.6-gke.0
```

I tried

```
terraform apply
```

again and presto the deployment finished.

Since I have excellent connectivity 
this smels like a google plugin bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the error (`Error: Failed to create deployment: Post https://32.244.226.151/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments: dial tcp 35.242.229.150:443: i/o timeout`) when I tried to create a deployment for a cluster which I had just created (via terraform).

What solved the problem for me was to reconnect kubctl to the cluster:

`gcloud container clusters list`
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials PUT_CLUSTER_NAME_HERE`

**UPDATE:**
I added this:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
   host     = "${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
   client_certificate     = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_certificate)}"
   client_key             = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_key)}"
   cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Submit the job - Terraform doesn't yet support StatefulSets, so we have to
 * shell out.
 * See: https://github.com/sethvargo/vault-on-gke/blob/master/terraform/gcp.tf
 */
resource "null_resource" "apply" {

  depends_on = ["google_container_node_pool.primary_preemptible_nodes"]
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}" \
  --project="${google_container_cluster.primary.project}"

gcloud container clusters list
EOF
  }
}
```

which **solved** the issue completely for me. 
Note: my cluster resource is `resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" { ... }`